# Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath' in latest version of Android studio 2022

Tags: android, build, android-gradle-plugin, android-support-library

I was trying to use my 1-year-old source code in the latest version of Android studio. I'm encountering a lot of issues. I've not been able to find any reasonable solution till now. I would really appreciate it if anybody could help me out.
Gradle code below:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    namespace 'gwyn.myapp'
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "gwyn.myapp"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'

    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.12.0'
    implementation 'com.github.clans:fab:1.6.4'
    implementation 'com.hbb20:ccp:2.2.3'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'
    implementation 'com.github.hani-momanii:SuperNova-Emoji:1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.0'
}
```

> Project: gwyn.app

```
plugins 
{
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.3.0-beta05' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.3.0-beta05' apply false
}
```

> Error I'm receiving

```
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
    
    Caused by: org.gradle.internal.execution.fingerprint.InputFingerprinter$InputFileFingerprintingException: Cannot fingerprint input file property 'externalLibNativeLibs': Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
    
    Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
    
    Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionNotFoundException: Could not find com.hbb20:ccp:2.2.3.
```

Thank you,